# GPX to Features 000814 error

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, gpx, error-000814

I have exported 3 route map .GPX files from the Ordnance Survey website for use in ArcGIS 10.2.2 for Desktop. I have tried to use the GPX to Feature Toolbox, but it keeps giving me an 000814 invalid file type error.

The same file imports correctly into the ESRI online Map Viewer.

I have read the Help page on this tool, but could not see any restrictions on compatibility other than GPX version 1.0 or 1.1, and I could not see any obvious defect on the XML coding for these files.

Can anyone give me guidance on what the issue may be? I have attached a copy of one of the GPX file coding for reference (see below.)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

-<gpx xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd" version="1.1" creator="OSMaps" xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:os="https://ordnancesurvey.co.uk/public/schema/route/0.1" xmlns:gs="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/gpx_style/0/2" xmlns:gh="https://graphhopper.com/public/schema/gpx/1.1">


-<metadata>

<name>Run 1</name>

<bounds minlon="-1.46011624452580" minlat="50.776773108592" maxlon="-1.42088800956398" maxlat="50.809363243217"/>

</metadata>


-<rte>

<name>Run 1</name>


-<rtept lon="-1.42178258804105" lat="50.797250104498">

<ele>19</ele>

</rtept>


-<rtept lon="-1.42233348544744" lat="50.795724082952">

<ele>22.1</ele>

</rtept>


-<rtept lon="-1.42338864591216" lat="50.793571065514">

<ele>21.8</ele>

</rtept>


-<rtept lon="-1.42404722797080" lat="50.791933158913">

<ele>17.9</ele>

</rtept>


-<rtept lon="-1.42437525972446" lat="50.791215365190">

<ele>15.7</ele>

</rtept>


-<rtept lon="-1.42399562524111" lat="50.790359190246">

<ele>15.5</ele>

</rtept>


-<rtept lon="-1.42403965045814" lat="50.789662476898">

<ele>13.7</ele>

</rtept>


-<rtept lon="-1.42383763249154" lat="50.788784695953">

<ele>11.5</ele>

</rtept>


-<rtept lon="-1.42600673687002" lat="50.788323269788">

<ele>10</ele>

</rtept>


-<rtept lon="-1.42542257816289" lat="50.786791643713">

<ele>5.9</ele>

</rtept>


-<rtept lon="-1.42508145322976" lat="50.785688363085">

<ele>3.8</ele>

</rtept>


-<rtept lon="-1.42492095772791" lat="50.784316191598">

<ele>1.4</ele>

</rtept>


-<rtept lon="-1.42450976934122" lat="50.783145118534">

<ele>4.5</ele>

</rtept>


-<rtept lon="-1.42409611717062" lat="50.782176366565">

<ele>4.7</ele>

</rtept>


-<rtept lon="-1.42449554793546" lat="50.781413960409">

<ele>5.2</ele>

</rtept>


-<rtept lon="-1.42624320255696" lat="50.780590744063">

<ele>6.7</ele>

</rtept>


-<rtept lon="-1.42777942169217" lat="50.779654056627">

<ele>8.2</ele>

</rtept>


-<rtept lon="-1.43034218801666" lat="50.778857254406">

<ele>12.9</ele>

</rtept>


-<rtept lon="-1.43272840161778" lat="50.777992092817">

<ele>14.1</ele>

</rtept>


-<rtept lon="-1.43507446991420" lat="50.777508876537">

<ele>14.5</ele>

</rtept>


-<rtept lon="-1.43876296019358" lat="50.777436746921">

<ele>14.5</ele>

</rtept>


-<rtept lon="-1.44134615256422" lat="50.777876293120">

<ele>13.6</ele>

</rtept>


-<rtept lon="-1.44490002083168" lat="50.777196319932">

<ele>11.7</ele>

</rtept>


-<rtept lon="-1.44575680080317" lat="50.776705795493">

<ele>13.3</ele>

</rtept>


-<rtept lon="-1.44865859263270" lat="50.777191655766">

<ele>14.7</ele>

</rtept>


-<rtept lon="-1.45113076359277" lat="50.778035130463">

<ele>14.9</ele>

</rtept>


-<rtept lon="-1.45231476023039" lat="50.779884188585">

<ele>14.8</ele>

</rtept>


-<rtept lon="-1.45328557058435" lat="50.781777198751">

<ele>16.7</ele>

</rtept>


-<rtept lon="-1.45396780110643" lat="50.784096001335">

<ele>20.9</ele>

</rtept>


-<rtept lon="-1.45430174846934" lat="50.785873611971">

<ele>22.8</ele>

</rtept>


-<rtept lon="-1.45452331567664" lat="50.788167773093">

<ele>24</ele>

</rtept>


-<rtept lon="-1.45460722383355" lat="50.790101583934">

<ele>24</ele>

</rtept>


-<rtept lon="-1.45505573609026" lat="50.791182796069">

<ele>24.7</ele>

</rtept>


-<rtept lon="-1.45529642758560" lat="50.791835886120">

<ele>25.2</ele>

</rtept>


-<rtept lon="-1.45596142973772" lat="50.792603362174">

<ele>25.5</ele>

</rtept>


-<rtept lon="-1.45200641821942" lat="50.794136090123">

<ele>24.3</ele>

</rtept>


-<rtept lon="-1.45248959011287" lat="50.795284918909">

<ele>24.9</ele>

</rtept>


-<rtept lon="-1.45265329021452" lat="50.796454729298">

<ele>20.1</ele>

</rtept>


-<rtept lon="-1.45327261857067" lat="50.798098787509">

<ele>22.2</ele>

</rtept>


-<rtept lon="-1.45502999533995" lat="50.799500863702">

<ele>27.4</ele>

</rtept>


-<rtept lon="-1.45618677114700" lat="50.800697782141">

<ele>24.4</ele>

</rtept>


-<rtept lon="-1.45677601434793" lat="50.801892048883">

<ele>19.3</ele>

</rtept>


-<rtept lon="-1.45701652329179" lat="50.802567614774">

<ele>22.7</ele>

</rtept>


-<rtept lon="-1.45845853097779" lat="50.803653428595">

<ele>27.7</ele>

</rtept>


-<rtept lon="-1.45979391641728" lat="50.804761212440">

<ele>28.1</ele>

</rtept>


-<rtept lon="-1.45822774655376" lat="50.805203584696">

<ele>34.1</ele>

</rtept>


-<rtept lon="-1.45577748598104" lat="50.805394520276">

<ele>34.2</ele>

</rtept>


-<rtept lon="-1.45492342080777" lat="50.805615350657">

<ele>34.1</ele>

</rtept>


-<rtept lon="-1.45370120918356" lat="50.806981011285">

<ele>34.7</ele>

</rtept>


-<rtept lon="-1.45237826738500" lat="50.807851592461">

<ele>33.4</ele>

</rtept>


-<rtept lon="-1.45106501955782" lat="50.807890387123">

<ele>32.7</ele>

</rtept>


-<rtept lon="-1.44908956082376" lat="50.806914373885">

<ele>31.9</ele>

</rtept>


-<rtept lon="-1.44585014498812" lat="50.807820783462">

<ele>21.1</ele>

</rtept>


-<rtept lon="-1.44300248275401" lat="50.808594083888">

<ele>11.3</ele>

</rtept>


-<rtept lon="-1.44164970996744" lat="50.808969807201">

<ele>6.3</ele>

</rtept>


-<rtept lon="-1.44040201336072" lat="50.809458426355">

<ele>5</ele>

</rtept>


-<rtept lon="-1.43887906112197" lat="50.809226299836">

<ele>5.4</ele>

</rtept>


-<rtept lon="-1.43552228091617" lat="50.808063555954">

<ele>3.4</ele>

</rtept>


-<rtept lon="-1.43117582797231" lat="50.806603635971">

<ele>3</ele>

</rtept>


-<rtept lon="-1.42778340227814" lat="50.805485457712">

<ele>3.6</ele>

</rtept>


-<rtept lon="-1.42527390795426" lat="50.804708754779">

<ele>1.6</ele>

</rtept>


-<rtept lon="-1.42486115666735" lat="50.803650087546">

<ele>3.2</ele>

</rtept>


-<rtept lon="-1.42458921916360" lat="50.802682039241">

<ele>2.5</ele>

</rtept>


-<rtept lon="-1.42474850024032" lat="50.801266484417">

<ele>2.9</ele>

</rtept>


-<rtept lon="-1.42465394384260" lat="50.800299309939">

<ele>3.9</ele>

</rtept>


-<rtept lon="-1.42380037960700" lat="50.800474952034">

<ele>-1.3</ele>

</rtept>


-<rtept lon="-1.42228168192038" lat="50.799927886549">

<ele>-1.3</ele>

</rtept>


-<rtept lon="-1.42101271457162" lat="50.799269632266">

<ele>-1.3</ele>

</rtept>


-<rtept lon="-1.42156282916298" lat="50.797811055738">

<ele>16.4</ele>

</rtept>

</rte>

</gpx>
```

Comment: Does your GPX file have an actual .GPX extension? The tool only works with `*.gpx` files.

Comment: The only other way you could get that error is based on the output name - what is the output value you're giving the tool?

Comment: @KHibma, thanks for your comments. I have finally resolved this issue and will post the answer below. I have looked on the ESRI help website  but could not find a reason for why the tool does not recognise a *.gpx file that is stored in a geodatabase.

Comment: You wont find that information in the help - its not something you can do. The only way to get a .gpx file into a .gdb would be to copy it manually in windows explorer and I'd think that would break the GDB. You shouldnt be using windows explorer to play with the contents of a .gdb "folder"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Error was resolved when I moved the .gpx files out of the File Geodatabase (.gdb) in which they were stored, and into a Windows File Folder. The tool does not seem to accept any *.gpx file located in a *.gdb folder.

Comment: A file geodatabase should not be treated as a folder, for example pasting data into it using windows explorer. See help section File geodatabases and Windows Explorer: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/administer-file-gdbs/file-geodatabases-and-windows-explorer.htm